# Is there a way to login user in an iframe (origin abc.com) on website 123.com

Tags: php, laravel, session, cross-domain-policy

i have a website abc.com
I have posts on that page where user can vote, add arguments and comments.
I am providing embed code(iframe) to embed my post detail page on other websites, Example 123.com
But now user is not able to login inside the iframe because of cross domain cookies policy. Iframe on 123.com do not show the user logged in even if user is logged in into the website(xyz.com) in same browser.

My website is built in laravel. Let me know if any information is required and let me know if there is any solution for this. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You need to read about [CORS](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#cors).

Comment: Hi @KurtFriars, Not sure if i am following you properly. I studied the cors and allowed it in my project, but still login inside the iframe do not work. Can you please explain if there is anything else that i need to to follow?